# How to properly use mechanize to scrape AJAX sites

Tags: javascript, python, json, mechanize, scrape

So I am fairly new to web scraping. There is this site that has a table on it, the values of the table are controlled by Javascript. The values will determine the address of future values that my browser is told to request from the Javascript. These new pages have JSON responses that the script updates the table with in my browser.

So I wanted to build a class with a mechanize method that takes in an url and spits out the body response, the first time a HTML, afterwards, the body response will be JSON, for remaining iterations.

I have something that works but I want to know if I am doing it right or if there is a better way.

```
class urlMaintain2:    
    def __init__(self):

        self.first_append = 0
        self.response = ''

    def pageResponse(self,url):
        import mechanize
        import cookielib        

        br = mechanize.Browser()

        #Cookie Jar
        cj = cookielib.LWPCookieJar()
        br.set_cookiejar(cj)

        #Browser options
        br.set_handle_equiv(True)
        br.set_handle_gzip(False)
        br.set_handle_redirect(True)
        br.set_handle_referer(True)
        br.set_handle_robots(False)

        br.set_handle_refresh(mechanize._http.HTTPRefreshProcessor(), max_time=1)

        br.addheaders = [('User-agent','Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.1; en-US; rv:1.9.2.16) Gecko/20110319 Firefox/3.6.16'),
                              ('Accept-Encoding','gzip')]
        if self.first_append == 1:
            br.addheaders.append(['Accept', ' application/json, text/javascript, */*'])
            br.addheaders.append(['Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'])
            br.addheaders.append(['X-Requested-With', 'XMLHttpRequest'])
            br.addheaders.append(['User-agent','Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.1; en-US; rv:1.9.2.16) Gecko/20110319 Firefox/3.6.16'])
            br.addheaders.append(['If-Modified-Since', 'Thu, 1 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT'])
            cj.add_cookie_header(br)   

        response = br.open(url)
        headers = response.info()

        if headers['Content-Encoding']=='gzip':
            import gzip
            gz = gzip.GzipFile(fileobj=response, mode='rb')
            html = gz.read()
            gz.close()
            headers["Content-type"] = "text/html; charset=utf-8"
            response.set_data(html)
        br.close()
        return response
```

self.first_append becomes positive after the data has been extracted from the main page html, so the br.addheaders.append don't run the first time through since there is no JSON in the body response, but all the other body responses are JSON. Is this the correct way to do this? Is there a more efficient way?

self.first_append becomes positive after the data has been extracted from the main page html, so the br.addheaders.append don't run the first time through since there is no JSON in the body response, but all the other body responses are JSON. Is this the correct way to do this? Is there a more efficient way? Are there other languages/libraries that do this better?

After a long period of running I get this error message:

```
File "C:\Users\Donkey\My Documents\Aptana Studio Workspace\UrlMaintain2\src\UrlMaintain2.py", line 55, in pageResponse response = br.open(url) 
File "C:\Python27\lib\mechanize_mechanize.py", line 203, in open return self._mech_open(url, data, timeout=timeout) 
File "C:\Python27\lib\mechanize_mechanize.py", line 230, in _mech_open response = UserAgentBase.open(self, request, data) 
File "C:\Python27\lib\mechanize_opener.py", line 193, in open response = urlopen(self, req, data) 
File "C:\Python27\lib\mechanize_urllib2_fork.py", line 344, in _open '_open', req) File "C:\Python27\lib\mechanize_urllib2_fork.py", line 332, in _call_chain result = func(*args) 
File "C:\Python27\lib\mechanize_urllib2_fork.py", line 1142, in http_open return self.do_open(httplib.HTTPConnection, req) 
File "C:\Python27\lib\mechanize_urllib2_fork.py", line 1118, in do_open raise URLError(err) urllib2.URLError:
```

It kind of has me lost, not sure why it is being generated but I need to have tons of iterations before I see it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the [mechanize faq](http://wwwsearch.sourceforge.net/mechanize/faq.html#general) "mechanize does not provide any support for JavaScript", it then elaborates on your options (the choices aren't great).

If you've got something working then great but using [selenium webdriver](https://selenium.dev/#the-5-minute-getting-started-guide) is a much better solution for scraping ajax sites than mechanize

Comment: Would you happen to know of any tutorials on selenium, concerning what I trying to do? Is there a particular language I should use with selenium? I really just learned python while attempting this project and have no real devotion to it. I do like my Aptana Studio though.

Comment: @Never You can use python and java with Selenium Webdriver. Python is a very cool language to learn and would be a great choice for this project.
There isn't much in the way of tutorials as it's very simple, this http://seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.html#the-5-minute-getting-started-guide is in java and c#, the python one would be almost exactly the same, but it will just use the python api.
Please mark my answer as correct if you feel it is.

Comment: You could also try out PhearJS (https://github.com/Tomtomgo/phearjs), which uses PhantomJS.