# Fill out Ajax forms in Python

Tags: python, ajax, mechanize, mechanize-python

I'm trying to fill forms of an ajax box (just my term for those several forms) using the mechanize module, but it seems not to work. I'm not a web programmer but afaik the ajax box updates itself 'onchange' with an event which is handled by the browser.

Mechanize seems not to handle that, in the links list (from the iterator Browser.links) I can find a url 'javascript:AjaxRetry();' with an error msg as text which tells me that something has gone wrong.

Here is my code:

```
import mechanize as m

br = m.Browser()
br.open(url)

br.select_form(nr=0)

# fill in one form (in a real browser, the other form refresh and are not disabled anymore)
br.set_value(code, br.form.controls[10].name)

# how to make it refresh now?
#br.submit() doesn't work (also br.click() does not work (no clickable around at all))
```

Is mechanize the right module to fill forms of that ajax box?

I can't paste the link to the page where that ajax box is, because you have to be logged-in in order to see that box.

Comment: Please show us the code.

Comment: Off the top of my head, Mechanize only exposes a browser-like API. You'd have to interpret the JavaScript yourself.

Comment: as I said, i'm not a web programmer. So how do i interpret the JavaScrpt myself? I know how to look at the java script code, but I don't know how to execute that myself from within mechanize?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mechanize doesn't handle javascript, see this answer for more details and an alternative solution [How to properly use mechanize to scrape AJAX sites](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6417801/how-to-properly-use-mechanize-to-scrape-ajax-sites/6420721#answer-6420721)