# Fill out HTML-InputFields which are not located in a form with Python mechanize

Tags: python, html, forms, mechanize

I want to fill out a HTML input field with mechanize which looks like this:

```
<input type="text" id="xy" name="xyz" [and some others] />
```

The problem: It is not located in a form, so br.select_form(...) don't work. How can I gain access to this field? Selecting the global form and br['xyz'] don't work, too. There is also a second input field which even doesn't have a name to address.

Comment: hi, did you  figure this out?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like javascript puts the form/fields on the page, Mechanize doesn't handle javascript, see this answer for more details and an alternative solution [How to properly use mechanize to scrape AJAX sites](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6417801/how-to-properly-use-mechanize-to-scrape-ajax-sites/6420721#answer-6420721)