# how to parse a dynamically updating .jsp form using python mechanize?

Tags: javascript, python, beautifulsoup, mechanize, web-scraping

I'm learning how to use Python Mechanize to scrape some data. For the most part, it's working, but one problem I've run into is that the .jsp page I'm looking at updates dynamically instead of using a 'submit' button.

I'm running into two related issues as a result:

1) There are multiple SelectControls I need to set on the page. The items of the second SelectControl are not populated until I've set the first SelectControl. How do I refresh the page with the first SelectControl set to my desired value (in a 'real' browser window, this happens automatically as I select an option from the first dropdown). I've tried using response() and reload() methods of the browser object, but these erase the value I assigned to the first SelectControl.

2) The data I would like to scrape appears dynamically when the SelectControl control values are set. Again, I need to somehow refresh the browser to reflect those values, but there's no submit button.

Answer (score 0):

Mechanize doesn't handle javascript, you could replicate what the javascript does (eg find out the possible values and build/select it manually). See this answer for more details and an alternative solution [How to properly use mechanize to scrape AJAX sites](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6417801/how-to-properly-use-mechanize-to-scrape-ajax-sites/6420721#answer-6420721)